# can't understand array in php

Tags: php, arrays

Can somebody explain me this script?
I don't understand what is "$myarray[$myarray[i]]" ?

```
<?php
$myarray = array (1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 15, 42, 23, 53);
$sum = 2;
for ($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) {
 $sum += $myarray[$myarray[$i]];
}
echo $sum;
?>
```

Comment: its using the value as a key

Comment: When `$i` is `1`, `$myarray[$i]` is `2`, so it adds `$myarray[2]` (`3`) to `$sum`; when $i is `2`, `$myarray[$i]` is `3`, so it adds `$myarray[3]` (`5`) to `$sum`; when $i is `3`, `$myarray[$i]` is `5`, so it adds `$myarray[5]` (`15`) to `$sum`; etc

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
    $myarray = array (1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 15, 42, 23, 53);
    $sum = 2;
    for ($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) {
        $sum += $myarray[$myarray[$i]];
    }
    echo $sum;
?>
```

I'm assuming you know how loop is working LOL.

So, when the loop starts `$i = 0` then

```
$myarray[$myarray[$i]] => $myarray[$myarray[0]]  //$myarray[0] = 1 
So
$sum += $myarray[1] //here $myarray[1] = 2 (second index of array)
$sum += 2;   => this statement is equivalent to $sum = $sum + 2;
so, $sum = 4 when first iteration of loop completes.
```

when `$i = 1`

```
$myarray[$myarray[1]] => $myarray[$myarray[2]] (3rd index is 3)
$sum += $myarray[3]
```

Since last time `$sum` was `4`, so `4+3 = 7`, `$sum` is `7` now, and so on..

check this **[DEMO](http://ideone.com/f0rotC)**, this will clear you all.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You will get the values from the index.

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) {
 $sum += $myarray[$myarray[$i]];
}
```

Will do :

```
($myarray[0] = 1) $myarray[1] => $sum+2 
($myarray[1] = 2) $myarray[2] => $sum+3
($myarray[2] = 3) $myarray[3] => $sum+5
($myarray[3] = 5) $myarray[5] => $sum+15
($myarray[4] = 8) $myarray[8] => $sum+53
```